# Why is (MathJaX help) not there, when you need it?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, asking-questions

I was asking a maths question and I don't know how to write the integral. So I'm starting to look for the MathJaX from **Faq page** but not there, I go to **main page** not there, I go to **about page** not there. I go to **ask question**still not there and finally **edit equestion** and i found MathJaX (http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/).

**I would like to suggest to put the MathJaX in main page or menu bar above the asking question box.**
MathJaX isn't the one of the important thing in asking maths question.

thanks.

Comment: To whom it may concern: editing [this section](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) (adding, for instance, a link to [this](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#supported-latex-commands)) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We try to keep [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) "featured", which makes it show up in the "Community Bulletin" box on the right hand side the main page on Math.SE. So you **should have** seen it on the main page.

It can also be found if you go to the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) on main and follow the link to our [detailed list of FAQs](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange) (which has been recently re-organized).

But you are right, it should be more prominently placed. I've edited the FAQ page to include some direct links to MathJax help. Anything more can only be done by the SE team.

Comment: Just a note: [many people find the harvard tutorial too intimidating/extensive](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82/tex-tutorial-too-intimidating-extensive) (it really has a lot of extra stuff that doesn't work in mathjax.) You may want to make your own tutorial and bug a comm team member to update the link. Like http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here

Comment: @Manishearth: the link included in the FAQ page on Main now is not to the harvard tutorial, but to MathJax's homepage and an official list of supported MathJax commands.

Comment: Not the faq link, the link on the sidebar that you get when writing a question. You need to bug a dev for it.

Comment: @Manish: Ah. I see. Thanks.

Comment: Shog said he'll ask a dev about it, but he probably forgot.. I just bugged balpha, if you want I can tell him to try it out for you guys as well.

Comment: @Manish: thanks, that would be appreciated. If you do, can you ask him to change it to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773 ? I don't have the time to write a tutorial right now, but when I do I'll probably just add it as an answer there.

Comment: OK. I'll copy-paste my post, cauterizing off the chem part as an answer there later, then you can just post your answer as an edit to the post. (Otherwise a user may have to sift through the answers there)